# Parsing a json string format = {TEST:[1,2,3,4]} by Gson

Tags: java, json

How do i parse the following String into json.

```
String jsonString="
{\"TEST64\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST59\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST65\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST57\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST66\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST67\":[1,0,18,0],
 \"TEST58\":[2,0,13,0],\"TEST55\":[1,0,17,0],\"TEST68\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST69\":[2,0,18,0],\"TEST56\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST53\":[2,0,13,0],
 \"TEST54\":[1,0,17,0],\"TEST70\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST52\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST51\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST61\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST60\":[2,0,14,0],
 \"TEST63\":[2,0,18,0],\"TEST62\":[1,0,18,0]}";
```

I am using gson, and trying to convert into MAP but get an exception:

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

and get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting array but found object:       java.lang.Object@4c5e176f
at   com.google.gson.JsonArrayDeserializationVisitor.startVisitingObject(JsonArrayDeserializationVisitor.java:89)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:119)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:67)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:52)
at com.google.gson.MapTypeAdapter.deserialize(MapTypeAdapter.java:68)
at com.google.gson.MapTypeAdapter.deserialize(MapTypeAdapter.java:33)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:92)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:80)
at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:101)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:76)
at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:54)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:551)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:521)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's on the left hand side of your convert call? seems that you are assigning the result to a incompatible map

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no problem with me. I am using Gson-2.2.4. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {           
            String jsonString = "{\"TEST64\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST59\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST65\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST57\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST66\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST67\":[1,0,18,0],\"TEST58\":[2,0,13,0],\"TEST55\":[1,0,17,0],\"TEST68\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST69\":[2,0,18,0],\"TEST56\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST53\":[2,0,13,0],\"TEST54\":[1,0,17,0],\"TEST70\":[2,0,17,0],\"TEST52\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST51\":[1,0,16,0],\"TEST61\":[2,0,16,0],\"TEST60\":[2,0,14,0],\"TEST63\":[2,0,18,0],\"TEST62\":[1,0,18,0]}";
            HashMap m = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
            System.out.println(m);              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code converted the json string into HashMap successfully. The Key of hashMap is String, and the value is ArrayList.

Output:

```
{TEST64=[1.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST59=[2.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0], TEST65=[2.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST57=[1.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST66=[2.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0], TEST67=[1.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0], TEST58=[2.0, 0.0, 13.0, 0.0], TEST55=[1.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0], TEST68=[1.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST69=[2.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0], TEST56=[1.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST53=[2.0, 0.0, 13.0, 0.0], TEST54=[1.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0], TEST70=[2.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0], TEST52=[2.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST51=[1.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST61=[2.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0], TEST60=[2.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0], TEST63=[2.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0], TEST62=[1.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any problem

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("E:/file.json")));  
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap fromJson = gson.fromJson(br, HashMap.class);

System.out.println(fromJson);
```

and it shows me map containing String as key & ArrayList as value (what you want)

My file.json contains your json string.

Hope this may help .